# Is the reflective property of a parabola unique?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, plane-curves

> The reflective property states that if a parabola can reflect light, then light that enters it travelling parallel to the axis of symmetry is reflected toward the focus.

[image: parabola]
(Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#/media/File:Parabel_2.svg)

Is parabola the unique curve with this property (i.e. "parallel to axis of symmetry" $\implies$ "reflected toward a single point") or are there other ones?

And is there a curve with a stronger property, namely *any* rays of light hitting the curve would be reflected toward a single point?

Comment: For instance, an ellipse has two focal points, as opposed to the parabola.

Comment: @jasnee in an ellipse, it's a ray from the other focus that always hits a focus, rather than rays parallel to the axis of symmetry.

Comment: @dbx Oops, missed that... You're right!

Comment: @Nomas, in putting together an answer, I ran across this site: https://blog.mathteachersresource.com/?tag=angles-of-incidence-and-reflection which you may like to read.

Comment: *"And is there a curve with a stronger property, namely **any** rays of light hitting the curve would be reflected toward a single point?"* That would be an *exceedingly* strong property, as it requires all rays hitting *any particular point on the curve* to reflect toward the single point. Conversely, a ray *from* that single point *to* any particular point on the curve would have to reflect *in all directions*.

Comment: @Blue Does that mean that no such curve exists?

Comment: Well, one might technically exist, an "empty shape" with nowhere for the rays to hit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a ray to be reflected at any point of the curve, then the curve must possess a tangent at every point, i.e. it must be represented by differentiable functions. (This immediately rules out the possibility that different rays incident at $P$ could be reflected at a same point).

Let's then set up a cartesian frame, having its origin at focus $F$ and $y$ axis parallel to the direction of the axis of symmetry of the curve.
If $P=(x,y)$ is any point on the curve, then the reflective property implies that the tangent at $P$ is the bisector of angle $FPH$, where $PH$ is parallel to the axis. It follows that the tangent at $P$ meets the $y$ axis at a point $Q$ such that $FQ=FP=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.
Hence we get for the derivative $y'(x)$, which is the slope of $PQ$, the following equation:
$$
y'(x)={1\over x}\left(y+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right).
$$
This can be solved to:
$$
y={a}x^2-{1\over4a},
$$
where $a$ is an arbitrary integration constant. And this is indeed the equation of a parabola.

[image]