# Is the reflective property of an ellipse unique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euclidean-geometry

Let F1 and F2 be the foci. It is known that in every ellipse with F1 and F2 being its foci, verifies the following property:a ray of light
which starts from F1 and is reflected in that curve, will then pass through F2.
Proof that only the ellipses verify that
property using differential equations.

I've been having a hard time trying to prove this question,if someone can give me at least a hint, it'll be much appreciated.
There is a similar question here:[Is the reflective property of a parabola unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4206129/is-the-reflective-property-of-a-parabola-unique). In this case is a parabola.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I'm sure you mean "ellipse" instead of "elliptic curve" which has a different meaning.

Comment: You're right, thanks. It has been corrected.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what it could mean to prove that other curves don't have this property—other curves don't have foci at all, so how could they have this property?

Comment: The idea is to suppose that we have a curve with foci that verifies that property, and get a differential equation which solution is an ellipse. But I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: See [here](https://www.matem.unam.mx/~omar/notes/conicrefl.html)

Comment: Hint : You can assume WLOG that $F_1(-1,0), F_2(1,0)$. Consider a generic tangent with equation $y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ Call $S$ the symmetric point of $F_2$ with respect to this tangent and $I$ the midpoint of $[F_2S]$. This midpoint 1) must belong to the tangent  (first constraint) 2) be such that the slope of line $IF_2$ be $-\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}$ (second constraint). Out of this, you will obtain a relationship between $f'(x_0), f(x_0) and x_0$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the hint, but would you be kind to give me more details please?. $y - y_0= f(x_0)(x-x_0)$ is the generic tangent and $y-0=-\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}(x-1)$ is the line through F2 and I, these are the two equations that you are talking about, but I don't see very clear how can I get an ellipse of this, Thanks.

Comment: I am going to give you more details in a partial answer.

Comment: It will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

One can assume WLOG that $F_1(−1,0),F_2(1,0)$.

Let $y=f(x)$ be the unknown cartesian equation (assumed differentiable) of a curve having the reflecting property.

Let us consider a point of the curve $T(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0:=f(x_0)$.

The tangent to the curve in $T$ has equation

$$y−y_0=f′(x_0)(x−x_0)\tag{1}$$

Let $S(x_1,y_1)$ be the symmetrical point of $F_2$ with respect to this tangent and

$$I\left(\frac{1+x_1}{2},\frac{y_1}{2}\right)$$

the midpoint of line segment $[F_2S]$.

Due to orthogonality, we have the following zero dot-product : $\vec{F_2S}.\vec{TI}=0$, giving the constraint

$$x_1-1=-y_1f'(x_0)\tag{2}$$

As point $I$ belongs to the tangent, we have :

$$\frac{y_1}{2}−y_0=f′(x_0)\left(\frac{1+x_1}{2}−x_0\right)\tag{3}$$

A last constraint, the most important because it is equivalent to the reflection property, is that $S(x_1,y_1)$ is aligned with $F_1$ and $T$, a relationship that can be expressed in the following way (consider it as an equality between slopes):

$$\frac{y_1}{x_1+1}=\frac{y_0}{x_0+1}\tag{4}$$

Using (2), (3) and (4), one obtains the following relationship :

$$1+x_1=2-y_1f'(x_0)=\frac{y_1-2y_0+2x_0f'(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}=\frac{y_1(x_0+1)}{y_0}\tag{5}$$

Eliminating $y_1$ between the two last equations,  we get the following condition:

$$f'(x_0)^2x_0 f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x_0^2-f(x_0)^2-1)- x_0 f(x_0) = 0\tag{6}$$

(without shame, I have done it with the assistance of a Computer Algebra System... see details in remark 3 below),

(6) can be written, taking a neutral notation :

$$f'(x)^2 (x f(x))-f'(x)(f(x)^2-x^2+1) - (x f(x)) = 0\tag{6'}$$

Considering (6') as a quadratic expression in $f'(x)$, we get $f'(x)$ by using on it the roots' formula, giving the following differential equation :

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2 x f(x)}\left((f(x)^2-x^2+1)\color{red}{-} \sqrt{(f(x)^2-x^2+1)^2+(2 x f(x))^2}\right)\tag{7}$$

One can check graphically, using for example Geogebra (see Fig. below) that this differential equation and its twin differential equation (with a $\color{red}{+}$ in front of the square root) give rise to elliptical arcs, knowing that it can be done in a rigorous manner (see Remark 2 below).

[image]

*The big blue dot illustrates an initial point with, attached to it, its trajectory. Please note that these trajectories stay either into quadrants (II) and (III) or into quadrants (I) and (IV). The small blue dots are the foci.*

**Remarks :**

1. There is a lot to say about the (maximum) domains of validity, but this is not the objective here...
2. One can check that the solutions of differential equation (6) and its "twin differential equation" are the curves with cartesian equations :

$$y=b\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{b^2+1}}$$

i.e., ellipses intersecting the axes in $(0,\pm b)$ and $(\pm \sqrt{b^2+1},0)$.

3. The symbolic Matlab program I have written for the obtention of eq. (6) :

   ```
    syms x0 y0 x1 y1 fp
    E1=2-y1*fp;E2=(y1-2*y0+2*x0*fp)/fp;E3=y1*(x0+1)/y0;
    Y11=solve(E1==E2,y1); % first way to express y1
    Y12=solve(E2==E3,y1); % second way
    [N,D]=numden(Y11-Y12); % reduction to a same denominator
    factor(N)
    % gives -2*fp*(fp^2*x0*y0 + fp*x0^2 - fp*y0^2 - fp - x0*y0)
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you be kind to explain a bit more the step (4)(I don't see why its that iff true) and how do you obtain the below equation and do you solve the differential equation? I've tried to solve it but didn't make it. Thanks for everything!

Comment: Solving that differential equation is not necessary: just check that the equation of an ellipse with those foci is a solution, and that uniqueness of the solution holds.

Comment: @vic I just added a graphical application using Geogebra. Besides, you are right, I have rectified (4) : the first equation (only) was good.

Comment: @Intelligency pauca : you are right : it suffices to check that all homofocal ellipses with those foci (i.e., with equation $\frac{x^2}{b^2+1}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ are solutions.

Comment: There is an error in (5), $1+x=\frac{y_1(x_0 +1)}{y_0}$, because if you consider the line that goes through F1 and T, it has this equation $y=\frac{y_0}{x_0+1}(x+1)$ and S belongs to this line: $y_1=\frac{y_0}{x_0+1}(x_1+1)$

Comment: @vic You are right. Just corrected.

Comment: Can you provide details of the Computer Algebra  System that you used?, please. Because I've tried to eliminate $y_1$ doing $2-y_1f'(x_0)=\frac{y_1-2y_0+2x_0f'(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$ and $2-y_1f'(x_0)=\frac{y_1(x_0+1)}{y_0}\$. I got two equalities for y_1 and don't get the same differential equation, it is probably a writting error.

Comment: It is the Matlab symbolic toolbox ; I am going to give you some details.

Comment: See in Remark 3 (that I just added) the Matlab (symbolic toolbox) program I have used.

Comment: I finally understood every step. Thanks for your help @JeanMarie !

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary curve in 2D $f(x,y)=0$. E.G.  $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=0, $the equation of an ellipse .

Arbitrary foci: $\vec{r_1}=<a_1,b_1>, \vec{r_2}=<a_2,b_2>$.

Law of reflection says angle of incidence with respect to the normal is angle of reflection with respect to the normal.The angles have different orientations though, so some sign complications can arise.

The normal to a curve in 2D is $\nabla f$. Let $\vec{r}$ be a vector pointing to the point on the curve.

We want to find an $f$ so that $\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}|}\cdot \nabla f =- \frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|}\cdot \nabla f$ where we use the minus sign because of the different orientation of the relevant angle mentioned before.

This suggests $\vec{q}=\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}|}+\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|}$  is $\vec{0}$ or perpendicular to $\nabla f$.

Consider the derivative with respect to a parametrization of the curve $\vec{r}(\lambda): \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda}$. That's a tangent vector at $\vec{r}$. It's in the same plane as $\nabla f$ and perpendicular, so up to a sign, $d\vec{r}/d\lambda = \hat{k}\times \nabla f$.

Using some vector identities:

$\vec{q}\cdot (\hat{k}\times d\vec{r})=\hat{k}(\vec{q}\cdot d\vec{r})-d\vec{r}(\vec{q}\cdot \hat{k})=0\implies \vec{q} \cdot d\vec{r}=0$

Now suppose $|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}|+|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|=c$, the definition of an ellipse.

$(d/d\lambda)(|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}|+|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|)=\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda}\cdot (\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_1}|}+\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r_2}|})=0$

So $ \int \frac{d\vec{r}}{d\lambda} \cdot \vec{q} d\lambda=$ sum of distances to foci= constant. We have an ellipse.